# Downloaded file's weight is 0 ko

Tags: java, android, outputstream, urlconnection

Working on a project for school, I got some issues with my work (new to Android developpement). I need to download file from url, so i looked on internet how to do that, i try to follow a tutorial but i got a problem, the file seems to be downloaded (i can see the file on my phone) but the file is 0,00 ko. Here is the code :

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    new DownloadFileFromURL().execute();
}

class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png");
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();


            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                    8192);

            // Output stream
            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/sb/test2.png");

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(root);

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    }
}
}
```

If anyone have some clues, that will be really great. Thanks.

Comment: Um, you don't write anything to your output stream, so yes, it will be empty. Hint: you're not reading anything from `input` either... which bit of code did you expect to be copying the data from the `InputStream` to the `OutputStream`?

Comment: Ok so i'm feeling really dumb now. I correct that and now it works perfectly. Thanks for the quick response and sorry for that stupid question.